# Adding an identifier in the order information in Shopify that is passed to our 3rd party fulfillment center

Tags: tags, shopify, liquid, checkout, fulfillment

Would it be possible to have an identifier in the order information that is passed to our 3rd party fulfillment center that would enable them to put an insert in the orders being shipped to different groups of customers? I've heard something about adding tags to orders but I'm still sifting through documentation for this -- hence posting my question here :-)

Comment: I think this documentation link helps you [Link](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/shopify-admin/productivity-tools/using-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do it...

You could use metafields:
https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/metafield

Or you could add an attribute to the properties in line-items itself:
[image: Add properties to line-items object]

https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/orders/order

This last way is how we did it with a major retailer - worked a charm!

Comment: Thanks! So how would you write it if you had say 3 different groups of customers and depending on each individual group it would instruct the fulfillment center to add different inserts, brochures or extras to the order?